# How do I add a file to a zipped file when using 7-zip?

Tags: 7-zip

I used to be able to drag & drop and add a file to a zipped folder. Now I cant when using 7-zip. I upgraded to a new computer with windows 8 (nightmare) that has 7-zip and I would either like to be able to add files to a zipped folder or install the old version of zipping files from Windows 7.

The "add" button inside the zipped folder on 7-zip does not work. It seems once I select the files I want to zip I am not allowed to add additional files to the zipped folder.  I used to be able to do this using windows 7.

I don't understand a lot of computer lingo like "archive" "extract" "directory" (I really try to but seriously, I just get more confused when I try to look this stuff up) so please simplify any answers as best as you can.  I apologize if my answer is already listed somewhere, I did look but only got more frustrated and confused.

Comment: 12 years and still the same bug...

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is drag the file you want to add into the 7-zip file manager window (the one you get if you right-click the zip folder and choose **7-Zip->Open Archive**)

Comment: Normally this will work, but if 7-Zip is run as Administrator then it won't.

Comment: @NateS For security reasons, Windows does not let you drag-and-drop into applications running as an admin. This is not specific to 7-Zip. https://superuser.com/questions/59051/drag-and-drop-file-into-application-under-run-as-administrator

Answer (score 0):

Well, a "directory" is just another name for a folder, and an "archive" is another name for a zipped folder. To "extract" a zipped folder just means to get the files out of it, by whatever method you choose. Now, to business: The [7-Zip documentation](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/fm/plugins/7-zip/add.htm) includes some information on how to do what you're attempting.

> Add to Archive Dialog Box
>
> Allows you to specify options for creating or updating an archive.
>
> How to call this dialog box
>
> In Windows Explorer or in 7-Zip, right-click the file(s) or folder(s) you want to compress.
>      Point to 7-Zip, and then click the Add to archive... command item.

In other words, it looks like the thing to do is, rather than starting from the zipped folder, start by highlighting the file(s) you want to add, and use the "Add to archive..." item in the right-click context menu. That should pop up a dialog asking you to locate the archive (zipped folder) you want to add the files to, and that should be about all you need to do. (There will be a lot of other options in that dialog box, I think, judging by the documentation -- but all of them should have sensible defaults, which are options chosen right from the start, so you should be able to safely ignore them.)

Comment: Hi there! Thank you!  This is what I have been doing but occasionally I have to update one of the files that has already been zipped.  When I do this, I have to delete the entire zipped folder and then create a brand new zipped folder making sure to replace all of the other files I originally had in there.  (hope that makes sense)  It would be easier to update the one file, delete it from the zipped folder and then copy and paste the new version to the zipped folder or drag N drop like I used to.  There is no way to do this in 7zip?

Comment: @Michelle Not really. The way you're used to doing it works because Windows has archive handling built right into the system, so that you can treat a zipped folder like any other -- but that works with a different type of archive, a type which 7-Zip can create but by default doesn't (and I'm not sure how to set it up so it does). That said, 7-Zip *is*, according to its documentation, smart enough not to have to recreate the whole thing if you just want to update a file or two; it is necessary to do it via the method described above, rather than drag-and-drop, but that method should work.

Comment: Aaron, I can't thank you enough for your help!  So just so I make sure I understand.  When I update a file that I have already zipped. The file is automatically updated inside the zipped folder?  Using 7zip I don't have to replace the old file with the updated version inside the zipped folder?

Comment: @Michelle: Have you tried just dragging the file you want to add into the 7-zip window? The window you get if you right-click the zip folder and choose **7-Zip->Open Archive**

Comment: @James - trying that right now.. *fingers crossed*

Comment: @Michelle Not quite -- when you put files in a zipped folder, they're copied, so changing the original file won't update the one in the zipped folder. I'm thinking James's method will probably work better than the one I found; sorry, I'd probably be more help if I could actually install a copy of 7-Zip to see how it works for myself.

Comment: @James IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  YAY!  This is what I needed!!!  OMG! If you only knew how much time this saves me! I had my two computers networked together so that I could share files back and forth... it was so confusing!  You guys are the absolute GREATEST!! You have no idea how grateful I am to you both!  Thank you soooooo much!!!!! :D