# windows drag&drop:how to disable dropping to a specific application?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, drag-and-drop

As we all know, we can drag and drop contents between applications. for example:
drag a file from Explorer to a notepad window.
drag an mail from Outlook to a word window to attach it.

The problem I'm having here it that, for this specific application(I'll call it A), some users can drag emails from outlook to A to make it an attachment in A, some users can't(the cursor changes to a STOP sign once entered A's window).

I'm just wondering if there's some settings, maybe security settings, that can disable dropping to a specific application(or a group of applications).

I'm out of my wits here. I'd really appreciate it you guys can give some clues. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the applications are run as different users (run as administrator for example) you may run into this problem. Additionally, running a program as the current user but with UAC elevation may cause the same behaviour.

I ran into the exact same issue with Skype, which needed to be run as an administrator in order to work with a hardware call answer button on a headset (through an intermediate driver and application that ran with admin privileges). Once Skype was run as an administrator the headset functionality was enabled, but I lost the ability to drag-drop from explorer.

Also see [Drag and Drop File into Application under run as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/59051/drag-and-drop-file-into-application-under-run-as-administrator?rq=1)